# search tuple in a quadruple in Python

Tags: python, tuples

I have a set of quadruple ('myTup') and a tuple ('tupleToSearch'). I need to search all instance of this tuple into each quadruple. 'tupleToSearch' will be compared agaimst first two elements of each quadruple and if matched then last two elements of the matched quadruple will be reported.

I am using the following code to do the same.

```
myTup = set([('0994900', '50.2297', 'name1', '<4'),
             ('2176041', '24.2880', 'name2', 'POSITIVE'), 
             ('2240663', '51.2510', 'name3', '25.0'), 
             ('2240663', '51.2510', 'name4', '29.0'), 
             ('2240663', '51.2560', 'name4', '29.0')])

tupToSearch = ('2240663', '51.2510')


[(x[2],x[3]) for x in myTup if tupToSearch == (x[0],x[1])]
```

I need to extend this code so that instead of exact search, it performs a comparison on range.

For example, given `tupleToSearch =  ('2240663', '51.2510')`, I want to find those quadruples whose second element is  >= 51.2510 but less than  (51.2510 + offset). Here 'offset' is a constant.

The correct answer in the above case will report last three quadruples (only last two elements from each of these).

How to convert the second element into numeric value for correct comparison.

Also, I need an efficient way to do this as I need to repeat this step almost  a billion times.

Comment: Where exactly did `51.27` come from?

Comment: I am adding a constant to the second term

Comment: @NPE, I edited the original post. I am adding an 'offset' to the second element. This offset is constant

Comment: *“I need an efficient way to do this”* – Then you should index your tuples by the first element (which apparently matches identically) and make sure it is then sorted by the second value so you can abort the iteration as soon as you exceeded the offset.

Comment: @poke That would be a good idea, except it looks like his dataset includes entries with duplicate keys, so it would be difficult to convert the data to a structure that won't destroy input data.

Answer (score 0):

Filter out the elements you want, then pull off the chunk of each element to create your result.

```
[(el[2], float(el[3])) for el in itertools.ifilter(lambda oel: oel[0] == search_tup[0] and float(search_tup[1]) <= float(oel[1]) <= float(search_tup[1]) + offset, my_tup)]
```

Alternatively, do the whole thing in a single pass with a generator (note that the generator, unlike the list comp, will gracefully handle cases where `el[3]` cannot covert to a float).

```
def filtered_data(input, search_target, offset):
    key = search_target[0]
    value = float(search_target[1])
    for entry in input:
        entry_value = float(entry[1])
        if entry[0] == key and entry_value <= value <= entry_value + offset:
            try:
                result_value = float(entry[3])
            except ValueError:
                result_value = entry[3]
            yield (entry[2], result_value)

[filtered_data(my_tup, search_tup, .019)]
```

Note that since you are using floating point values here, your filtering process will always be subject to the inerrant inaccuracies introduced when floating point decimal values are converted to floating point binary values.  As a result, you may want to use `Decimal` or build an offset in to the base value as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's the [float function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float), that can be used to write this code:

```
low_target = float(tupToSearch[1])
high_target = low_target + constant
[(x[2],x[3]) for x in myTup if low_target<=float(x[1])<=high_target]
```